# Wordpress query posts with exclusion

Tags: wordpress

This is what I have to query all events...

```
 query_posts("post_type=marcato_show&meta_key=marcato_show_start_time_unix&orderby=meta_value&order=ASC&posts_per_page=999" );
```

and this works, just getting the community events...

```
query_posts( "post_type=marcato_show&showtype=community-events&meta_key=marcato_show_start_time_unix&orderby=meta_value&order=ASC&posts_per_page=999" );
```

how do I go about getting all the events WITHOUT the community events?

Comment: Add &cat=-999, Where 999 is the id of the category you want to exclude (notice the - before the cat_id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Rather than using `query_posts()`, which can cause a number of issues (see [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts)), I'd recommend using the [WP_Query class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/).**

This will avoid some obscure bugs, speed up the query for you, and also make it easier to make changes like excluding posts assigned to a certain term (in this case, the `community-events` term of the `showtype` taxonomy).

Be sure to read up on the [WP_Query documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) as it covers a lot of useful arguments you may need in the future. But for now, here's how you'd run your same query, excluding those posts in `community-events`:

```
$posts = new WP_Query(array(
  "post_type" => "marcato_show",
  "meta_key" => "marcato_show_start_time_unix",
  "orderby" => "meta_value",
  "order" => "ASC"
  "posts_per_page" => 999, // you can also use `-1` to return unlimited results
  "tax_query" => array(
    array(
      "taxonomy" => "showtype",
      "field" => "slug",
      "terms" => "community-events",
      "operator" => "NOT IN",
    ),
  ),
));

if($posts->have_posts()){
  while($posts->have_posts()){
    $posts->the_post();
    // DISPLAY YOUR POSTS HERE
}

wp_reset_postdata(); // restore original post data
```

This is querying with the same arguments you used in your original post, with the added `tax_query` to query posts not in that custom taxonomy term. Scroll down to *Taxonomy Parameters* at the WP_Query documentation linked above for full details on how this works.